# In MPAndroidChart Library, How to wrap X Axis Labels to two lines when long?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to show X axis label to go to 2 lines when they are long. How to achieve this in LineChart? See screenshot below. I want time to go to second line instead of staying next to date

[image]

Comment: So in other words you want a line break between the date and time when the date and time are too long? How do you plan on detecting/defining if it's too long or not though?

Comment: @Ultimater - I was thinking may be to depend it on number of characters.

Comment: @NinjaCoder, did you figure out a way to do it?

Comment: @FelipeMosso I don't think that is possible sadly :(

Comment: did you find any solution for this? @NinjaCoder

Answer (score 43):

For those like me who want to achieve this but keep the original library, here is a simple solution inspired by @fgueli's modifications. This applies for one break line only (add "\n" in your labels) but you can easily adapt it to your needs.

1. Subclass XAxisRenderer

   ```
   public class CustomXAxisRenderer extends XAxisRenderer {
       public CustomXAxisRenderer(ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, XAxis xAxis, Transformer trans) {
            super(viewPortHandler, xAxis, trans);
       }

       @Override
       protected void drawLabel(Canvas c, String formattedLabel, float x, float y, MPPointF anchor, float angleDegrees) {
           String line[] = formattedLabel.split("\n");
           Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, line[0], x, y, mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees);
           Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, line[1], x + mAxisLabelPaint.getTextSize(), y + mAxisLabelPaint.getTextSize(), mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees);
       }
   }
   ```

---

1. Set this renderer on the desired chart

   ```
   lineChart.setXAxisRenderer(new CustomXAxisRenderer(lineChart.getViewPortHandler(), lineChart.getXAxis(), lineChart.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT)));
   ```

---

3. Enjoy!

[image: LineChart labels on multiple lines]

Comment: Please include the plot in your answer and not a link, the link later can break and your answer will be incomplete

Comment: @Ibo I am sorry but I can't: _You're not allowed to embed images in your posts yet, so we've included a link instead. As soon as you earn 10 reputation on the site, you'll be able to embed images._

Comment: This solution is not working for HorizontalBarChart when setting LEFT YAxis to enable false for hiding it. And when using RIGHT YAxis for getting transformer it is giving `12-19 18:46:19.631 10003-10003/com.aegisisc.samplecharts A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 10003 (sc.samplecharts)`

Comment: @GuillaumeJounel - Its not working for me. Just showing  line[0] value, text after "\n" is not drawn. Can you Pls help me.

Comment: How I can use this solution with the radarchart ?

Comment: @RahulParihar, just increase viewport offsets, so 2nd line can be seen, like so: chart.setViewPortOffsets(0, 0, 0, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.radiobutton_size)); and radiobutton_size is 36dp in my case (with 8dp text size)

Comment: BTW, if one wants to get multiline text centered (so line[0] will be above line[0] centered), he shouldn't use `Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, line[1], x + mAxisLabelPaint.getTextSize(), y + mAxisLabelPaint.getTextSize(), mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees);` but instead `Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, line[1], x, y + mAxisLabelPaint.getTextSize(), mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees);`

Comment: Possible index out of bounds error? What about if there is only 1 line: `line[] = ... split("\n")` will be a 1 index array and `line[1]` will break?

Comment: Works nearly perfect. Both lines are slightly overlapping. How can I put more space between them?

Comment: --> got it: in drawXAxisValue(...) are x and y used to set the size. The thing is, that this is calculated from the original orientation of the label. So using rotation (-45) will make it overlap again. We need pythagoras here.

Comment: Or if you know it keeps -45 just use the original solution of this answer and do not change as suggested by comment of RomanT. (this all only in case of use of the improvement of answer of @Peter B.

Comment: This solution worked for me in a Vertical Bar Chart. In a Horizontal Bar Chart doesn't work. I noticed that the y value passed to the drawLabel method is always 28. and all the label are printed one on the other. Can you help me ? Maybe I have to change the transformer ?

Comment: thank you both @GuillaumeJounel and RomanT. i am affraid about this stuf in many times. now it is solve. good answer.

Comment: Can I drawable to text with this approach?

Answer (score 19):

I modified the library to allow multiline label on the xAxis using \n

https://github.com/fabriziogueli/MPAndroidChart/tree/axis_multiline_labels

It is working right now but need further testing and maybe some code styling / adjustment.

```
XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setMultiLineLabel(true);
```

Then you can use for example a SimpleDateFormat like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy\nHH:mm a");
```

Maybe you have to set extra bottom offset to your chart:

```
mChart.setExtraBottomOffset(50);
```

Comment: Can you maybe include some snippets from the classes that you used inside the answer? I am assuming you have to modify the renderer somehow and maybe the `Utils` class

Comment: Yes, i modified the XAxisRenderer and Utils classes. You can see the changes here: https://github.com/fabriziogueli/MPAndroidChart/commit/6c5f22bf3b1f359052618d51a76fbf8ee07e0444

Comment: This works well, hopefully it will get folded into the main project ASAP!  Is there anyway to center the text?  Right now, it is left justified, which looks odd.  Thanks!

Comment: @Bourne you are right, there was a problem with the alignment. I fixed it. Check the new version here: https://github.com/fabriziogueli/MPAndroidChart/tree/axis_multiline_labels.

Comment: @fabriziogueli Awesome, that works nicely!  I would just note for anyone wanting to use it, that the second line is still left justified with the first line, so it isn't line-per-line centered.  That is probably going to take a more robust solution with multiple strings (arraylist maybe)? But the current alignment fix makes it a whole lot better and, for my purposes, I was able to make it look pretty good with just adding an extra space in the second line (i.e. I used "MMM d\n yyyy" instead of "MMM d\nyyyy").

Comment: Even thought using compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1', getting error on setMultiLineLabel() as cannot resolve. Will you pleaase help me out @fabriziogueli

Comment: @Tara yes because this feature is not present in the official library. If you want to use this version, you have to download it from here:

https://github.com/fabriziogueli/MPAndroidChart/tree/axis_multiline_labels

Comment: I did this, by creating a sample program from downloaded project and gave longer labels for x axis, but again result is same.

Comment: @Tara you have to set the correct valueFormatter on the XAxis object and use a SimpleDateFormat with '\n"

Comment: mpandroidchart 3.1.0 has same issue it is not work setMultilielable. ould you fix it?

Answer (score 8):

Improved version of @Guillaume Jounel's answer to support multiple newlines, as well as strings w/o a newline.

```
@Override
protected void drawLabel(Canvas c, String formattedLabel, float x, float y,
                             MPPointF anchor, float angleDegrees) {
String line[] = formattedLabel.split("\n");
Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, line[0], x, y, mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees);
    for (int i = 1; i < line.length; i++) { // we've already processed 1st line
         Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, line[i], x, y + mAxisLabelPaint.getTextSize() * i,
             mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great, but I needed to add extra space below the chart like so: `chart.setExtraOffsets(0.toFloat(), 0.toFloat(), 0.toFloat(), xLabelExtraHeight)`

Comment: Can I add drawable to text with this approach?

Answer (score 7):

This looks like something that you will have to implement yourself by modifying the library to your needs.

It is currently not possible by default to have multiple lines on the x-axis. The reason therefore is that Android `Canvas` cannot simply plot a string e.g. like this `"Line 1\nLine2"` as two lines.

Answer (score 4):

No need to offset x coordinate. And for multi-line scenario the code should be

```
@Override
protected void drawLabel(Canvas c, String formattedLabel, float x, float y, MPPointF anchor, float angleDegrees) {
    String lines[] = formattedLabel.split("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        float vOffset = i * mAxisLabelPaint.getTextSize();
        Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, lines[i], x, y + vOffset, mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Horizontal Barchart below solved the problem.

```
class CustomXAxisRenderer(viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?, xAxis: XAxis?, trans: Transformer?, chart: HorizontalBarChart) : XAxisRendererHorizontalBarChart(viewPortHandler, xAxis, trans, chart) {
    override fun drawLabel(c: Canvas?, formattedLabel: String, x: Float, y: Float, anchor: MPPointF?, angleDegrees: Float) {
        val line: List<String> = formattedLabel.split("\n")
        Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, line[0], x, y, mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees)
        for (i in 1 until line.size) {
            Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, line[i], x, y + mAxisLabelPaint.textSize * i,
                mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees)
        }
    }
}
```

and called as follows

```
barChart.setXAxisRenderer(CustomXAxisRenderer(barChart.viewPortHandler, xAxis, barChart.getTransformer(yAxis.axisDependency), barChart))
```

Comment: in this the starting offset of the label is wrong, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use the @Guillaume Jounel answer and then add:

```
XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();    
xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-30f);
```