# MPAndroidChart : Fix x Axis width or Break X axis text in two lines

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am working and android chart library using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/) .

I am using `HorizontalBarChart` to display chart.

Please see the attached image and I want do decrease x axis width or want to display x axis text in two lines is there any way to this ?[image]

Any help will get appreciate.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking or what result you want to achieve,

Comment: This question now has an answer here: [In MPAndroidChart Library, How to wrap X Axis Labels to two lines when long?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509174/in-mpandroidchart-library-how-to-wrap-x-axis-labels-to-two-lines-when-long)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to draw the x-axis labels in multiple lines.

What you can do to decrease the space the labels consume is to simply provide shorter labels. A axis label of the length you are showing above is too long for a chart to be easily readable anyway.

Comment: can you please add this options to library I tried to change it using `\n`but its not working.

Comment: @bhaveshkaila did you get any workaround? I am facing same issue, and tried with `\n` but not working... Interesting is that, `\n` is working with ios mpchart library :-)