# MPAndroidChart X Axis Label not wrapping

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using `BarChart` by [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) in my project.

I have some long labels in X Axis. as shown in a following screen shot.

[image]

I want to do wrap X axis label in multi-line.

Comment: @Philipp Jahoda,Dude I am also stuck into same issue could you please help me on same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In MPAndroidChart Library, How to wrap X Axis Labels to two lines when long?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509174/in-mpandroidchart-library-how-to-wrap-x-axis-labels-to-two-lines-when-long)

Comment: also this one: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1880