# MPAndroidCharts: Word wrap for BarChart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I have the next chart:

[image]

Is there any way to do word wrap for label description ?
I was trying to add '\n' symbol but it's not working for me.

Comment: Probably make the screen in landscape mode.  Which looks  much better. Obviously this is not the answer for your question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509174/in-mpandroidchart-library-how-to-wrap-x-axis-labels-to-two-lines-when-long

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a custom XAxisValueFormatter:

```
public class MyCustomXAxisValueFormatter implements XAxisValueFormatter {

    @Override
    public String getXValue(String original, int index, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        if(original.length() > 10)
        {
            original = original.substring(0, 6) + "\n" + original.substring(6, original.length());
        }
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Then apply it to your X-axis:

```
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();

xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyCustomXAxisValueFormatter());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply, but it's not working for me. Custom formatter successfully updated string but it is still all in one line.
Which version of library do you using ? Because me - MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5

Comment: I'm not using the library at all right now. Although, I used v2.0. something in one of my projects. If this doesn't help you, then I am not sure what to do. Also, this might be a [known issue](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/377).