# MPAndroidChart - "\n" does not work while setting ValueFormatter

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I wanna achieve such behavior seen below using `PieChart` of [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library.

[image: PieChart]

To do that, I'm setting the `ValueFormatter` of `PieData` as the following:

```
data.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
            if(value > 0)
                return floatFormat.format(value) + "\n(XXX)";
            else
                return "";
        }
});
```

However, the "\n" is somewhat ignored by the `ValueFormatter` or `PieChart`, and I'm getting the entire value in a single line. What could be the reason for that? How can I achieve multiline value label behavior as seen in the PieChart example seen above?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32509174/5241933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround solution, I set values I wanna show after new line breaks as labels of my `PieEntry` variables:

```
PieEntry entry = new PieEntry(value, "(XXX)");
```

Seems like it does what I wanted to achieve so far. However, it's still not understandable for me that why "\n" does not work while setting `ValueFormatter`.

Comment: It's because the renderer is only designed to render a single line of text for a value label. You would have to override `drawLabels()` inside a custom renderer